# How to select table from two tables using SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to table in SQL course and student

Course table has following fields

```
courseid coursename courseduration
```

Student table has the following fields

```
rollno  name  address courseid
```

I want the result as following

```
 BCA
   abc
   def
   pqr
 MCA
   stu
   ijk
 BTECH
   xyz
```

I am applying inner join for it like following suggest me query for desired result
My query is following:

```
SELECT student.name
FROM student
INNER JOIN course
ON student.courseid=course.courseid;
```

Comment: Indentation like that is best left to the presentation tier (e.g. on a web page). What you can do is include `coursename` in the select and also order by it. The screen will need to to the grouping and indentation.

Comment: You will also need to select on `course.coursename`, not just `student.name`. So you'll have `SELECT course.coursename, student.name`, etc.

Comment: why don't you group_concat `student.name` for each course?

Comment: Mr kusalananda can you suggest the query will it repeat the course name

Comment: instead of comment can anybody give the solution please

Comment: That's not hard if you explain me what are the BCA and abc, is the BCA coursename and abc student name?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
  course.name AS course_name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(student.name) AS student_name
FROM student
INNER JOIN course
ON student.courseid = course.courseid
GROUP BY course.courseid;
```

This will give you something like this:

```
Course_name   |  Student_name
BCA           |  abc,def,pqr
MCA           |  stu,ijk
BTECH         |  xyz
```

Comment: Just remember to group by `course.name` (not courseid) as it is non-aggregated select.

Comment: i dont want to show student name in different column please see my desired output and suggest for that if possible

Comment: @adeshsingh Can you explain your o/p?

Comment: See the desired output is given there like explained in my question check it please

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options

1) Include the course name in the select and order by it - it will be repeated on each row for the student in the course

```
SELECT course.name, student.name
FROM student
INNER JOIN course
ON student.courseid=course.courseid
ORDER BY course.name;
```

Which will return

```
Course Student
 BCA   abc
 BCA   def
 BCA   pqr
 MCA   stu
 MCA   ijk
 BTECH  xyz
```

You would do the indentation in your presentation tier, e.g. by indenting every time the course name changes.

2) You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all students into a single column for a grouping on Course_name

```
SELECT course.name, GROUP_CONCAT(student.name) AS Students
FROM student
INNER JOIN course
ON student.courseid=course.courseid
GROUP BY course.name;
```

Returns

```
 Course  Students
 BCA     abc, def, pqr
 MCA     stu, ijk
 BTECH   xyz
```

**Edit, re I just want one column**

Well, you can project and combine the course name and student names with a `UNION` into a single column, and use an ordering hack to associate the students [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee0b4a/12). In fact, you can even add spaces to get the indentation effect. But this is solving the wrong problem - this kind of formatting is presentation tier and shouldn't be done in Sql IMO.

```
SELECT Name
FROM
(
  SELECT course.coursename AS Name, course.coursename AS Course, 1 As RowType
  FROM course

  UNION ALL

  SELECT CONCAT('   ', student.name), course.coursename, 2 AS RowType
  FROM student
  INNER JOIN course
  ON student.courseid=course.courseid
) x
ORDER BY Course, RowType;
```

Returns

```
BCA
 abc
 def
 pqr
BTECH
 xyz
MCA
 ijk
 stu
```

Comment: I want the result in a single column like                                                                                                                                                                        BCA                                                                                                                 adesh                                                                                                             john                                                                                                           MCA ....... so on first course below student names

Comment: I've updated, but again, this kind of thing isn't for Sql. Its for screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT `name`
FROM(
SELECT course.courseid, course.coursename AS `name`
FROM course
UNION
SELECT student.courseid + 0.1 AS courseid, courseid.name AS `name`
FROM student
ORDER BY courseid ASC) AS ordered_list
```